# Understanding $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x+x}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x+x}{\sin x}$$

I don't understand the above expression. What is $x$? Radians? Degrees? Let's assume radians. If I want to find the limit, would I substitute $x$ with various values that gradually gets closer to $0$?

For example, $\frac{\sin 0.1+0.1}{\sin 0.1}$. $\sin 0.1$ radians is approximately $18^\circ$, which is approximately $0.2$ looking at a unit circle. But $0.2$ what? What do these numbers represent?

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin2x}{\sin x}$$ 
Is this accurate? Or is it $(\sin +x)+x$?

Comment: It's well-known that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1$

Comment: Values are almost always in radians in higher mathematics.

Comment: Thanks J.W. Tanner and N. Bar. The sin x /x = 1 confuses me further however. sin x gives a ratio. x in the denominator is a radian. Is it proper to just divide them like that? Or do I by coincidence get the correct answer doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little ambiguous but in serious maths the argument to $\sin$, $\cos$, etc would always be in radians.  I have never seen $\sin x + x$ interpreted as anything other than $(\sin x) + x$.  However, in this case the limit is $2$ in either interpretation.

Do you know Taylor series?  These will help you solve it.  For small $x$, $\sin(x)$ is close to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Either by series expansion or L'Hospital's Rule the limit can be evaluated. The angle $x$ is in radians unless specifically  mentioned otherwise.

Briefly: 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\,1+\dfrac{x}{\sin x}=1+1=2$$